# Display info from parent to sidebar in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I'm very new to React and I'm trying to create a UI that shows some basic info and then when you click on one of those info boxes it displays more detailed information in a sidebar component. I've written out a mock of what I'm currently working with (to write it all out would probably not be helpful).

I'm puzzled about how I deliver the information from the Table component to the Sidebar component. I've watched a few tutorials and looked through Stack Overflow but am still in the weeds. Any advice out there? And let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

```
// pretend we're using axios to get some JSON

function showInfo(){
    // on click this displays the Table info in the Sidebar
}

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
    render(){
    // create a UI that returns the clicked state of Table as props listed
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component { 
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { items: [] }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
  // pretend we're grabbing that JSON and put it into state.items
  }
  render(){
    // create a UI and map through the items
    <Sidebar></Sidebar>
  }
}
```

Comment: The only way to do it with the built-in `setState` method, you would have to use the most near parent/grand-parent of both components. If the structure gets to deep, consider to use a state management library like redux, or mobx.

Comment: Ok! I will look into doing the first suggestion. Barring that I guess I'll dive into Redux.

Comment: To expand on @webdeb's point:  the concept he is discussing is what the docs refer to as [lifting state](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html).  The downside is that it can sometimes mean snaking some prop through many child components before getting it where it is needed.  [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) is a state-machine library that comes with the bonus of allowing you to inject state directly where it is needed, without using several "pass-thru" components-- older blog posts/documentation recommends against this, but currently its considered a good practice.